# pythons subprocess hangs (no use of PIPE)

Tags: python-3.x, bash, process, subprocess

I am calling several bash scripts in a loop:

```
import subprocess

for script in scripts:
    cmd = './{}'.format(script)
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

My issue is that a few scripts will hang and I don't understand why.  It seems as though subprocess is just waiting after `script` has finished executing.  Note that I am not using stdout=subprocess.PIPE, etc, that the documentation specifically suggests can overflow a buffer and cause a related issue.

Any suggestions?  I can set `timeout` on the process, but would prefer not to resort to this measure.

When sigterm, the python output reads:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 269, in call
    return p.wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1457, in wait
    (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1404, in _try_wait
    (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
```

Comment: If Python is stuck on a `waitpid`, I'm guessing one of the scripts hasn't actually terminated. Is there any chance the scripts could be waiting on input or the like? If the scripts don't need input, would it be worth trying `cmd = './{} </dev/null'`? Also, what state does `ps aux` show `bash` to be in? If all else fails, I'd be tempted to run the Python script under `strace -f` and see what the system call the bash script is stuck on.

Comment: @Jon it could be waiting - this is helpful.  I'm not exactly sure where the hangup is coming from - I'm running code I didn't write.

Comment: @Jon I had seen pointing to dev/null elsewhere; what exactly is the thinking there?

Comment: The thinking with the `/dev/null` is that the subprocess can't block on input if there is no input :-) Thinking about this more, I think I'd install `strace` and run something like `strace -f python pythonscrypt.py`. It'll be noisy, but if the subprocess blocks on anything, you'll see exactly what system call is blocking. If it is a `read(0,`, you know you have a script waiting for standard input.